# MFi Controller center button element?

Tags: ios, swift, mfi

I am attempting to implement MFi controller compatibility with my project and all is going well so far. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcextendedgamepad) notes that for the `GCExtendedGamepad` class (which is the one I care about) there are several button elements:

> The controls associated with the extended gamepad profile include the following:
>
> - Two shoulder buttons.
> - Two triggers.
> - Four face buttons arranged in a diamond pattern.
> - One directional pad.
> - Two thumbsticks.

However, there is one last button right in the center of the thing. On my Nimbus controller it's a button labeled "Menu" but the diagram included in the official documentation page shows it as a pause button. Either way, I see no further mention of this button or any means of accessing it. Is there any way to handle input for this button specifically?

Comment: Same issue here, I tried the `GCExtendedGamepad` profile's `buttonMenu` and `buttonHome` but both are not triggered by the MFi (Steelseries Nimbus) controller.